# Karate - missing double quotes in the response of Runner.runFeature()

Tags: java, karate

I'm trying to get response in java after Runner.runFeature() execution however double quotes are removed from some of entities.

The feature file called is reading external json file.
Then dynamically changing values in karate and making post.

In output I see that the file have double quotes.
However after execution when I see in the response map double quotes are removed on some of objects.

Initial json file (sample.json):

```
{"d":{"ChangeRequestType":"AAA","AdditionalInformation":"bla","RequestReason":"test BP creation","BusinessPartner":{"BPCategory":"2","Description":"BLA","CentralData":{"Name1":"NYJKPEFB0818GR4","Name2":"NYJKPEFB0818GR4","NameOrg1":"LM60Q9ZBBXM4SHXWNJZK","NameOrg2":"LM60Q9ZBBXM4SHXWNJZK"},"TaxNumbers":[{"TaxNumberCategory":"XYZ","TaxNumberProperty":"999"}],"IdentificationNumbers":[{"IdentificationType":"BLA01","IDNumber":"123"}],"BankDetails":[{"BankdetailsID":"0001","BankNumber":"210","BankAccount":"12344","BankCountry":"DE","BankAccountName":"Hardcoded bank account"}],"Addresses":[{"AddressType":"1","PhysicalAddresses":[{"HouseNumber":"40","City":"Berlin","PostalCode":"1333","CountryKey":"DE","Street":"BLA"}]}]}}}
```

Feature file, reading external json file:

```
    * def entityCreate = read('..//utils/sample.json')


  Scenario:Post
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Creating unique BusinessPartner
    Given url uri
    And request entityCreate
    When method post
    Then status 201
```

Invoking feature file from JAVA class:

```
  Map<String, Object> resultCreate = Runner.runFeature(getClass(), "/../odata/businesspartner/businessPartnerCreateTest.feature", null, true);
```

Result of getting result from Runner:

```
 System.out.println(resultCreate.get("entityCreate").toString());
```

Result:

```
{d={ChangeRequestType=AAA, AdditionalInformation=bla, RequestReason=test BP creation, BusinessPartner={BPCategory=2, Description=BLA, CentralData={Name1=NYJKPEFB0818GR4, Name2=NYJKPEFB0818GR4, NameOrg1=LM60Q9ZBBXM4SHXWNJZK, NameOrg2=LM60Q9ZBBXM4SHXWNJZK}, TaxNumbers=[{"TaxNumberCategory":"ABC","TaxNumberProperty":"123"}], IdentificationNumbers=[{"IdentificationType":"ABC","IDNumber":"1234"}], BankDetails=[{"BankdetailsID":"0001","BankNumber":"210","BankAccount":"12345","BankCountry":"DE","BankAccountName":"Hardcoded bank account"}], Addresses=[{"AddressType":"1","PhysicalAddresses":[{"HouseNumber":"40","City":"Berlin","PostalCode":"1333","CountryKey":"DE","Street":"BLA"}]}]}}}
```

Some **" "** where removed and some remains.

Any help appreciated, I'm lost and most probably making silly mistake.

Comment: @Peter Thomas - can I copy payload after overriding values to a raw String ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are printing a string concatenation, behind the scenes the JSON is probably fine: https://github.com/intuit/karate#print

Otherwise, impossible to tell from what you have provided. Maybe you should follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I added more details - I hope that will explain a little bit more...

Comment: @PePe nope this is too complicated for me: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to be as minimal as possible - It looks for me like Runner is parsing this specific JSON structure and removing " from it. Request is created properly etc. I'm trying to grasp request to JAVA but I'm always getting it "corrupted".

Comment: Or parsing it in the wrong way...  `entityCreate=[type: MAP, value: {ChangeRequestType=AAA, AdditionalInformation=bla RequestReason=For test purpose, BusinessPartner={BPCategory=2, Description=bla, CentralData={Name1=test API, NameOrg1=Organisation}, Addresses=[{"AddressType":"1","PhysicalAddresses":[{"CountryKey":"DE"}]}]}}]` value from the object Map. Can I just pass plain text/string of request to Java then?

Comment: Ok I answered to myself - I think it was late yesterday. I just used * string =  entityCreate - haha.